# Count the number of keywords based on a list

Tags: r, filter

I have got a dataset called colours, in which I am interested to find some keywords based on a list (colouryellow , colourblue, colourwhite) that I have created. This is an example of the dataset:

| USER | MESSAGE |
| --- | --- |
| 23456 | The colouryellow is very bright! |
| 31245 | Most girls like colourpink |
| 99999 | I am having a break |
| 9877 | The colouryellow is like the sun |

**Is there a way where I can obtain the number of times each keywords based on the list appear on the column MESSAGE?**
For example, the output would be like:

| Keyword | Frequency of Keywords |
| --- | --- |
| colouryellow | 2 |
| colourblue | 0 |
| colourwhite | 0 |

I have tried the following code but it does not provide me the frequency for each keyword, instead displays them together.

```
   colour= read.csv("C: xxxxxx")

   keywordcount= dplyr::filter(colour, grepl("colouryellow|colourblue|colourwhite, MESSAGE))
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things you can do.

```r
some_colours <- c("colouryellow", "colourblue", "colourwhite")
some_col_regex <- paste0("\\b(", paste(some_colours, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")
grepl(some_col_regex, colour$MESSAGE)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
lengths(regmatches(colour$MESSAGE, gregexpr(some_col_regex, colour$MESSAGE)))
# [1] 1 0 0 1
table(unlist(regmatches(colour$MESSAGE, gregexpr(some_col_regex, colour$MESSAGE))))
# colouryellow 
#            2
```

---

Data

```r
colour <- structure(list(USER = c(23456L, 31245L, 99999L, 9877L), MESSAGE = c("The colouryellow is very bright!", "Most girls like colourpink", "I am having a break", "The colouryellow is like the sun")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```